# Jquery getScript showing ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've tried to load an external javascript (chat app) to my webpage by using below following code and its always giving ReferenceError: $ is not defined while my script and URL to the script is ok.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#customer-chat-button-toggle").click(function() {
         $.getScript('livechat/php/app.php/widget-init.js',function(){  
         async: false;
        })
    });     
});
</script>
```

Comment: Include jQuery correctly. A valid jQuery script must be referenced, the source JS file must be fetchable, and it must be placed before any script element which wishes to use $. (But make sure to use updated versions than in that question.)

Comment: I've tried with various possibilities

Comment: The error message isn't lying. There are only so many reasons this can occur. Is there a jQuery script specified *before* this script? Does fetching the jQuery source result in a 200 OK response? Has anyone called `jQuery.noConflict`?

Comment: I want to know why my question goes 2 negative mark? Whats makes it so poor ?

Comment: Please add the HTML where you have included your scripts, it would help to identify the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that jQuery is properly loaded. Use firebug as a Firefox debugger or the Chrome console.

Are you accessing a different domain? If so you will need to use a json callback.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://ihound.com.au/livechat/php/app.php/widget-init.js",
    jsonpCallback: "jsonpcallback",
    jsonp: false,
    dataType: "jsonp"
}).done(function(data){
   console.log(data); // array of objects
});
```

Comment: I've checked with you code and firebug still my async is true

Comment: $ undefined is because jQuery is not loaded before the jquery code is being executed. Are you loading jQuery in the header?

Comment: Glad I could help @Niharika Parida

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this editing a weebly site recently and they were including jQuery correctly.  I had to reference as jQuery.  After further reading their includes I could also get it via $$.  The console helped alot:

```
$
```

Should yield something like

```
function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}
```

If not try

```
jQuery
```

Should return same.